# JPA Persist ManyToMany with Generated IDs

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

**The question:**
Is it possible to cascade persist a ManyToMany relationship with additional columns in the join table where the IDs in both of the joining entities are generated?

**Additional Information:**
I have an application setup with Spring 4 and Hibernate. I have setup a ManyToMany relationship with additional columns on the joining entity by following the [method documented on WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns) (a ManyToMany relationship practically implemented by using a OneToMany relationship in each entity). Everything seems to work the way I have it setup EXCEPT for the cascade persist operation. I believe the issue is caused by the IDs for the Employee and Project entities not being generated until after Spring/Hibernate has already attempted to persist the ProjectAssociation entity.

I have tested this thoroughly and I have discovered that the IDs for both Employee and Project are being generated, but the ProjectAssociation entity is only populated with the EmployeeId before the Hibernate INSERT is logged for the ProjectAssociation (which fails due to a NULL value in a foreign key column). I have tried various kludges with @PrePersist, but the @PrePersist method is being called before both the Employee and Project entities have been assigned an ID.

Comment: I advice you to create new table which will be middle tier between tables Employee and Project and break that ManyToMany relationship into two OneToMany relationships.

Comment: @Forum999 Sorry if I was unclear. I followed the method recommended on WikiBooks which does use two OneToMany relationships (as you recommended).

Comment: is this creating new third table in db?

Comment: @Orion I'm not sure what you're asking. I have 3 tables, one for Employees, one for Projects, and one to join them in a ManyToMany relationship. The article that I linked to has the details on my implementation.

Comment: so if it doesn't work with one JPA provider have a quick test with another. I'm sure I've done something very similar with the one I use and all works. The JPA provider should always order the INSERTs to suit what generated values there are